# summarise_each for two variables

Tags: r, dplyr, summary

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    text = c(1:12),
    person = c(c(rep("John", 6)), c(rep("Jane", 6))),
    lemma  = c("he", "he", "he", "his", "it", "she", "he",
           "she", "she", "his", "it", "she"),
    n = c(8, 8, 3, 7, 10, 4, 12, 9, 3, 4, 2, 8),
    total_words = c(20, 49, 19, 39, 40, 30, 13, 30, 20, 34, 33, 15))
```

What I'm trying to do is to get summary statistics, so that I can tell the relative frequency of each pronoun with all the texts produced by John and Jane respectively. If all I wanted was the counts, it would be easy:

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
df %>%
   group_by(person, lemma) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum), n) %>%
   spread(lemma, n)
```

However, as I said, I need relative frequency, so I need to divide the above results to the total number of words in all the texts produced by John and Jane respectively. Getting the percentages is also easy:

```
df %>%
group_by(lemma) %>%
summarise_each(funs(sum), n, total_words) %>%
mutate(percentage = n / total_words)
```

What I want to to is replace the total counts in the first example with the percentages in the second example, and that is where I am stuck.

Comment: you should probably add expected output

Comment: Thanks. I'm away from my computer, but what I'm trying to do is to get the sum total, of, say, John's "his" across all six of his texts divided against the sum total of his total words (that is, the sum total of total_words across all six of his texts, but I want this for his pronouns and all her pronouns. I can get either the number of pronouns John and Jane each produced, and the percentages for all the pronouns, but I can't get the two in the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question over at manipulaR google and Brandon Hurr gave me an answer that I tweaked to get into the final form I wanted. Here it is, in case anyone else finds they need to do something similar:

```
wordPerson <- df %>%
  group_by(person) %>%
  summarise(sumWords = sum(total_words))

df %>%
   group_by(lemma, person) %>%
   summarise_each(funs(sum), n, total_words) %>%
   inner_join(., wordPerson, by = "person") %>%
   mutate(percentage = n / sumWords) %>%
   select(person, lemma, percentage) %>%
   spread(lemma, percentage)
```

In short, you need to do this in two stages.